# Reading and Analysing data from text file - Big issue

Tags: java, serialization, io, filewriter

This is what I have so far:

```
public class test1 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("IRStudents.txt"));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("File_2.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();



    for (int i = 1; i <= 10 && line != null; i++) {
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("- - - - - - - - - - -");
        bw.newLine();

        line = br.readLine();
    }


        System.out.println("Lines are Successfully copied!");

        br.close();

        bw.close();
    }

}
```

So right now text gets written into a new text document. The format is like this:(User ID Name)

```
25987 Alan
- - - - - -
25954 Betty
- - - - - -
```

etc

Now I got another file with UserID and Marks with a layout like this:

```
25220 68.7
25987 51.5
25954 22.2
```

Now I want to make a way for Java to analyse the UserID and merge the marks with the specific name and marks that it's associated to. For example this is what it should look like at the end.

```
25987 Alan
Marks: 51.5
- - - - - - 
25954 Betty
Marks: 22.2
- - - - - -
```

Now I know this is alot to ask and do not expect a full solution of code but i'm a very new java programmer and will appreciate advice and what direction i should take.

Thank You.

Comment: For something like this, you may want to consider building a small database...

Comment: You could read the files and store them seperatly in an `arraylist` and then compare the values of those 2 lists, if it finds a match either store that in a new list or in the first one if at creation there is made space for new strings. If it's all done, write a new file with the contents of the complete list.

Comment: @ryekayo It's just a small text files. Literally just reformatting and changing importing text

Comment: @WonderWorld Yeah I was thinking of using arraylists but just wondering if there is an easier way. Serialization/String Builders?

Comment: @bob9123 i would do some more research on how to read and write files. Your example code works, but thats only because there are 3 lines and you call `readLine()` twice. You would get a lot of problems if the textfile contained a lot of lines.

Comment: @WonderWorld It's like 12 lines max in a file

Comment: @bob9123 i would still use a `while`loop for it. `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {// do something (probably store the line in an arraylist)}`

Comment: @WonderWorld I see something about Serialization, will this be useful?

Comment: @bob9123 i don't have enough programming experience to say anything usefull about that. sorry.

Comment: @bob9123 Probably `Scanner` would be better so you can use the `nextInt()` method.

Comment: @WonderWorld I got it now, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this (with small datasets) is to store the data of one file and merge the data whilst reading the other file like in my code below (you did get a full solution after all :) )
Oh and please note that if you are going to work with huge datasets that you would probably want to use a database instead. And my code will not list users that do not have a mark (though you can fix that quite easily)

The code: (this code asumes that there is a file called IRStudents.txt and a file called Marks.txt)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    //declare reader and writer
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    //hash map to store the data of the first file
    Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //read the first file and store the data
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("IRStudents.txt"))));
    String line;
    String[] arg;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        if(!line.startsWith("-")){
            arg = line.split(" ");
            names.put(arg[0], arg[1]);
        }
    }
    reader.close();

    //read the second file, merge the data and output the data to the out file
    writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("File_2.txt")));
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("Marks.txt"))));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        arg = line.split(" ");
        writer.println(arg[0] + " " + names.get(arg[0]));
        writer.println("Marks: " + arg[1]);
        writer.println("- - - - - -");
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: 100% done it. Going through and understanding it now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hey is it possible to add another hash map to accommodate a new text file with student id and marks? Exactly like the old one but different marks

Comment: So you want to merge a file with ids/names with a file with ids/marks? In that case you can just change the names of the files in the code. Or if this is not what you want then I am afraid I do not understand your question if that's the case I will try to understand it better :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the 'RandomAccessFile' Class in tha java.io package. It allows you to specify file pointers that take you to any point in an existing text file for reading or writing, which it seems is what you would like to do.

Edit: I see you want to output merged data in a separate file. In that case the accepted answer is sufficient. I was thinking you wanted to modify your existing file to add lines mid-text

Here's the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class Student with three fields (UID, name and mark) and then use a HashMap with Integer (UID) as key and Student as value.

With that, read the first file and insert in the HashMap instances of Student with name set then read the second file and use the UID to find the corresponding student in the HashMap to set the mark.

Finally iterate over the HashMap to write the data to your output file.

Comment: Are `Hash Map's` the same as `Hash Tables`?